# There is already an object named '#BaseData' in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is a snippet of my code.

I am wanting to filter my data based upon a variable.

When I try to run the code, it returns an error of "There is already an object named '#BaseData' in the database.". I am not sure as to why this is the case; I have put extra checks within the IF statements to drop the temp table if it already exists but to no avail.

Are you able to help or provide an alternative solution please?

```
DECLARE @Variable AS VARCHAR(20) = 'Example1'

IF OBJECT_ID(N'TEMPDB..#BaseData') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #BaseData

IF @Variable = 'Example1'
BEGIN
  
SELECT
            *
INTO
            #BaseData
FROM
            [Database].[schema].[table]

END

IF @Variable = 'Example2'
BEGIN
   
SELECT
            *
INTO
            #BaseData
FROM
            [Database].[schema].[table]
WHERE
            [column] = 1

END

IF @Variable = 'Example3'
BEGIN
    
SELECT
            *
INTO
            #BaseData
FROM
            [Database].[schema].[table]
WHERE
            [column] = 0

END
```

Answer (score 1):

While code is compiled by SQL, creation of same #table is found in each condition so it doesn't work.
One possible solution would be to create table and than insert data conditionally.

```
-- DROP TEMP TABLE IF EXISTS
IF OBJECT_ID(N'TEMPDB..#BaseData') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #BaseData
GO
  
-- CRATE TEMP TABLE WITH TempId, AND SAME STRUCTURE AS YOUR TABLE
SELECT TOP 0 CONVERT(INT, 0)TempId, * INTO #BaseData FROM TestTable

-- DECLARE VARIABLE
DECLARE @Variable AS VARCHAR(20)= 'Example1'

-- INSERT DATA IN TABLE DEPENDING FROM CONDITION
IF (@Variable = 'Example1')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #BaseData SELECT * FROM TestTable
END

IF (@Variable = 'Example2')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #BaseData SELECT * FROM TestTable  WHERE Id = 1
END

IF (@Variable = 'Example3')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #BaseData SELECT * FROM TestTable  WHERE Id = 2
END
```